# Rewrite ignores "config"

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

It seems that rewrite ignores the word "**config**".

REQUEST_URI was `(my domain)/blahblah/config` and it does not work, while others(such as `(my domain)/blahblah/main`) do.

My sample .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blahblah/(.+)$ /something.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I guess that Apache(or mod_rewrite) ignores some words because of security.
I'd like to check what words are prohibited, or change its forbidden words list.
Where can I find it its list?